# Query help needed

Tags: sql, mysql

How do I select results from table T1 where

```
T1.itemID = T2.itemID
```

and no corresponding record found in T2, i.e. found only in T1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT …
  FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.itemid = t2.itemid)
  WHERE t2.itemid IS NULL
```

The more obvious query using NOT EXISTS runs slower older versions of MySQL. Thanks @OMG Ponies for [benchmarks in a newer (unspecified) version](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).

Here is the NOT EXISTS version:

```
SELECT …
  FROM t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.itemid = t1.itemid)
```

(Explanation, to answer comments: `LEFT JOIN` differs from `INNER JOIN` in that if there is no row in the right table, a row is still returned in the results but with all the columns=NULL.)

Comment: if t1.itemid = t2.itemid and t2.itemid IS NULL then wouldn't t1.itemid be null too? I'm confused :)

Comment: NOT EXISTS is slower **if the column(s) compared are not nullable** -- [if the columns are nullable, NOT EXISTS performs best of the options available](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/)

Comment: @Learning, @santa: Yes, that's the difference between INNER JOIN (or just JOIN) and LEFT JOIN. Added explanation to answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from T1 where ItemID not in (select ItemId from T2)
```

Comment: With MySQL, that's probably the slowest way to do it... MySQL will (at least last time I checked) actually build the result of that subquery as a temporary. (Actually, it appears from @OMG Ponies comment that they've fixed this)

Comment: yup , i agree. not exists is the way to go.